# Material components : change event in MDCCheckbox not working

Tags: javascript, html, material-design, material-components

I am using MDCCheckbox component of [material components](https://material.io/components/web/catalog/input-controls/checkboxes/). This is the html code

```
<div class="mdc-checkbox" data-mdc-auto-init="MDCCheckbox">
  <input type="checkbox"
         class="mdc-checkbox__native-control"/>
  <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
    <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark"
         viewBox="0 0 24 24">
      <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark__path"
            fill="none"
            stroke="white"
            d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59"/>
    </svg>
    <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to listen to change event on this element, so I have added listener

```
const cbEl = document.querySelector('.mdc-checkbox');

cbEl.addEventListener('MDCCheckbox:change', ({detail}) => {
    console.log(detail)
});
```

but this is not working. The same is working with MDCIconToggle component. Is this the correct way?

And how can I set its state to indeterminate?

And when I click on checkbox ripple effect get freezes. How to solve this?
Documentation is too poor.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
const cbEl = document.querySelector('.mdc-checkbox');
var checkbox = document.querySelector('.mdc-checkbox input');//Find your checkbox input

checkbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
    console.log(cbEl.checked); //will return true or false
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In [Google MDC checkbox](https://material.io/components/checkboxes/web#api) version 11.0.0 there isn't `MDCCheckbox:change` event. So you can do this:

```js
const checkbox = new mdc.checkbox.MDCCheckbox(document.querySelector('.mdc-checkbox'));
   
let checkboxInput = document.getElementById('checkbox-1');
checkboxInput.addEventListener('click', () => {
   // do something
});
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="mdc-checkbox">
   <input type="checkbox" class="mdc-checkbox__native-control" id="checkbox-1"/>
   <div class="mdc-checkbox__background">
       <svg class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
           <path class="mdc-checkbox__checkmark-path" fill="none"
                       d="M1.73,12.91 8.1,19.28 22.79,4.59"/>
       </svg>
       <div class="mdc-checkbox__mixedmark"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="mdc-checkbox__ripple"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The component should be initialized with `window.mdc.autoInit()`. Then call the `listen` method on `MDCCheckbox` to register a listener for the event:

```
window.mdc.autoInit();

const cbEl = document.querySelector('.mdc-checkbox');

cbEl.MDCCheckbox.listen('MDCCheckbox:change', event => {
    console.log(event)
});
```